# Unlisting a list of summary statistics into a dataframe in R

Tags: r, r-raster

I have extracted summary statistics (min, 1st quartile, mean etc) for raster pixels in 38 different polygons that are present in a shapefile as below

```
extracted_product<-extract(raster, shapefile, fun=summary, na.rm=TRUE)
```

extracted_product is a list with 38 elements (each representing a polygon) that contain the summary statistics. I want to get a dataframe with 38 rows representing the 38 polygons and the columns being min, 1st quartile, mean, etc. How do I do that? I have tried the following

```
x<-data.frame(unlist(extracted_product))
```

But I get a dataframe with one coloumn that contains the summary statistics i.e. 5 rows of min, 1st quartile etc is one polygon, which is not what I want.

Any suggestion would greatly help.

Comment: is each list item a regular vector?

Comment: @DavidPedack I don't think so. It is the type of variable you get on using summary()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't provide any data... so guessing a bit here:

```
myList = list(item1 = summary(c(1,2,3)), 
              item2 = summary(c(3,4,5)), 
              item3 = summary(c(8,8,8)), 
              item4 = summary(c(9,9,9))
```

if that's similar to what you have then

```
x <- do.call(rbind, myList)
```

Comment: that is exactly what I have and it worked! Much appreciate it!